# How do we address/what are good practices for "serverless" resource abuse?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-security-group

If I create a public endpoint using AWS API Gateway, the entire world could access it. This would be a problem because the end point would trigger an AWS Lambda function. If we assume that I can't query a data source to determine the frequency that the incoming IP address queried the resource in the past, what would be the best practice for protecting this end point from abuse? Do I have any other security options?

I realize I could use a reCaptcha but this would still invoke the AWS Lambda function and would incur costs if done a million times over a short window of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple way of protecting your API gateway

1. Use AWS Cloudfront with TTL 0 and pass custom headers from AWS Cloudfront to API gateway
2. Use AWS WAF with AWS Cloudfront

AWS API Gateway also handles some basic level of DDOS attacks.

Kindly also view these blogs for securing AWS API Gateway

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/protecting-your-api-using-amazon-api-gateway-and-aws-waf-part-i/

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/protecting-your-api-using-amazon-api-gateway-and-aws-waf-part-2/

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for throttling limit configuration or usage plan definition:

> To prevent your API from being overwhelmed by too many requests,
>   Amazon API Gateway throttles requests to your API using the token
>   bucket algorithm, where a token counts for a request. Specifically,
>   API Gateway sets a limit on a steady-state rate and a burst of request
>   submissions against all APIs in your account. In the token bucket
>   algorithm, the burst is the maximum bucket size.
>
> When request submissions exceed the steady-state request rate and
>   burst limits, API Gateway fails the limit-exceeding requests and
>   returns 429 Too Many Requests error responses to the client. Upon
>   catching such exceptions, the client can resubmit the failed requests
>   in a rate-limiting fashion, while complying with the API Gateway
>   throttling limits.
>
> As an API developer, you can set the limits for individual API stages
>   or methods to improve overall performance across all APIs in your
>   account. Alternatively, you can enable usage plans to restrict client
>   request submissions to within specified request rates and quotas. This
>   restricts the overall request submissions so that they don't go
>   significantly past the account-level throttling limits.

References:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-request-throttling.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-usage-plans-with-console.html#api-gateway-usage-plan-create

Comment: Fabio, this is per client, right? In other words, if I host my website using S3 ... there shouldn't be any limits as long as the client requests are unique?

Comment: @CharlesSaag, please take a look at the first reference I sent, in the section "How Throttling Limit Settings Are Applied in API Gateway". Throttling limits are applied per-client (as you said), but there are also server-side limits to prevent your API/account from being overwhelmed by too many requests.